# A very strange error with regards to Android's ViewFlipper and the first call to showNext() or showPrevious

Tags: android, viewflipper

I am currently developing an application and have run into a small error that I can hack to fix but I would prefer to know why my error occurs. I have a tabbed interface that uses the TabWidget to create three tabs. My error lies in the first tab where I have placed a ViewFlipper. The ViewFlipper is meant to flip between two different views (using two ViewStub's to connect to two previously designed layouts). Basically the first view has a button that when pressed should change the ViewFlipper in the current Tab to the next (or specified) view\layout. Now my error comes in when the application is launched for the first time. The very first request to the ViewFlipper (showNext or showPrevious or setDisplayChild) isn't registered. The next press (and presses of the button thereafter) correctly change the display. I have checked using LogCat whether the button actually calls the registered onClick function (defined in the xml layout) and the button does register the click. Once again the problem is specifically the very first call to the ViewFlipper view changing and every call thereafter works flawlessly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am willing to post the code if necessary but it is quite lengthy.

EDIT: Added code.

**Main XML**

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <!-- View 1 -->
                <ViewStub android:id="@+id/stub1"
                   android:inflatedId="@+id/subTree1"
                   android:layout="@layout/layout_tab1"
                   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

                <!-- View 2 -->
                <ViewStub android:id="@+id/stub2"
                   android:inflatedId="@+id/subTree2"
                   android:layout="@layout/layout_tab12" 
                   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
            </ViewFlipper>

            <ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/tab2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <!-- View 1 -->
                <ViewStub android:id="@+id/stub3"
                   android:inflatedId="@+id/subTree3"
                   android:layout="@layout/layout_tab2"
                   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

            </ViewFlipper>    
            <ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/tab3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <!-- View 1 -->
                <ViewStub android:id="@+id/stub4"
                   android:inflatedId="@+id/subTree4"
                   android:layout="@layout/layout_tab3"
                   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

                <!-- View 2 -->
            </ViewFlipper>         
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

**Tab 1 XML**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabone"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" 
        android:onClick="onButtonClick"/>

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textview1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:text="Tab 1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

*Application Code*

```
    TabHost mTabHost;
    TextView textCurrent;
    ViewFlipper viewFlipper;
    String tag = "Tag";
    int value = 0;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mTabHost = getTabHost();

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test1").setIndicator("TAB 1").setContent(R.id.tab1));
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test2").setIndicator("TAB 2").setContent(R.id.tab2));
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test3").setIndicator("TAB 3").setContent(R.id.tab3));

        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

        mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);

    }

    public void onButtonClick(View v)
    {
        if(v.getId() == R.id.button1)
        {
            Log.d(tag, "Button Pressed");
            viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.tab1);
            viewFlipper.showNext();

            /*
            //HACK TO GET NEXT BUTTON WORKING
            value++;
            if(value == 1)
             viewFlipper.showNext();
             */
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) { //Back key pressed
            mTabHost = getTabHost();
            if(mTabHost.getCurrentTab() == 0)
            {
                //Things to Do
                viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.tab1);
                viewFlipper.showPrevious();
            }
            else
            {
                finish();
            }
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    public void onTabChanged(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(arg0.equals("tab_test1"))
        {
            Log.d(tag, "Tab 1 Accessed");
            viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.tab1);
            int index = viewFlipper.indexOfChild(findViewById(R.id.subTree1));
            viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(index);   
        }
    }
```

Comment: I wonder if it has to do with using ViewStubs. Can you try the same set-up with the stubs replaced by the actual layouts?

Comment: Yip seems to work now.... Very weird. I need to somehow use other layouts though - the ViewFlipper seemed to have a problem with my use of a RelativeLayout within the viewFlipper.

Comment: I would just like to know if there is some way I could fix the error. Its all good and well that the ViewStubs cause the error (that is it isn't present when using them) but I would really like to use them (greatly simplifies my layout system).

Comment: Can you perhaps get some of the same simplifications using `include` tags?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a null pointer to me... check that all variables are initialized properly before the method runs the first time. Hard to tell what actually is going wrong without your code though.

Comment: viewFlipper isnt initialised until the button is pressed. you should move that to your onCreate method. edit: actually it doesnt matter cause you've initialised it each time you've used it